# Spring Data: Create entities (and DB entries) using boolean fields of another entity

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Boot, Spring Data and JPA Rest Repositories and MySQL as a database and I want to do several things when my entity is created.

Let's say I have a MainChecker entity and each of them has various Checkers that need to be created/deleted or updated whenever MainChecker is created/updated.

**This is what I want to do:**

Use Spring Data Repositories to insert MainChecker entities from the frontend to my database (so it would be a JSON with parameters).

Each of these MainChecker entities will have boolean fields (among others).

Based on these boolean fields, I want to CRUD other entities accordingly.
So, if a MainChecker has some boolean changed to false (redChecker, for example), I would like to delete that redChecker. But the other checkers would still remain (for example green and blue)

**Bonus problem!** One field is a JSON containing parameters that are to be used for creation of these other entities.

**A very simplified example:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="master_checker", catalog="checkers")        
public class MasterChecker() {

        private Long id;

        private Boolean blueChecker;
        private Boolean greenChecker;
        private Boolean redChecker;

    // constructors
    // getters and setters

        }
```

I have some ideas but not sure which one of them is a good way to go.

1. Should I put a @OneToOne relationship for each field? Then a Boolean won't do, it will have to be objects. And how do I create an object from a boolean value and insert parameters from my JSON field?
2. Make a custom getter and setter and create the object in the service layer (not liking this option very much)

How to do this (in an elegant and decent way)?

Comment: Have you looked at RepositoryEventHandlers, e.g. @BeforeCreate and @BeforeSave? These will allow you to add some extra logic during creation/update of an object, you can e.g. check those checkers and do required CRUD actions in a repository https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler

Comment: *How to do this (in an elegant and decent way)?* IMHO by having a `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` relationship between `MainChecker` and `Checker` entities. This is way more flexible than having a fixed number of booleans.

Comment: @dic19 I am receiving just a json with boolean values. And based on that I need to insert or delete other entities

Comment: @AdamKučera I actually haven't seen it. Looking at it right now, thanks...

Comment: @AdamKučera, I have actually used those handlers and built my logic around them eventually. If you post your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use RepositoryEventHandlers, e.g. `@BeforeCreate` and `@BeforeSave`.

It will allow you to add some extra logic during creation/update of an object, you can e.g. check if those checkers are true or false and do required CRUD actions in a repository.

See more in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler).